# Paypal ipn not accepting foreach loop

Tags: php, paypal, foreach, paypal-ipn

Since a couple of hours I'm trying to find out why the IPN from paypal isn't accepting a foreach loop inside.

If i write

```
if (strcmp (trim($res), "VERIFIED") == 0) {
$resDB = mysql_connect("localhost", "user","pass");
mysql_select_db("database", $resDB);
$files = array(
'key1' => 'value1',
'key2' => 'value2',
'key3' => 'value3'
 );
 foreach($files as $key => $value) {
 if($_POST['item_name'] == $key){
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO downloads (downloadkey, file, expires) VALUES ('{$strKey}', '$value', '".(time()+(60*60*24*7))."')");
}
};
}
ecc...
```

it's not working and i get a 500 error from the ipn simulator in the sandbox account, but

```
if(strcmp (trim($res), "VERIFIED") == 0) {
 $resDB = mysql_connect("localhost", "user","pass");
  mysql_select_db("database", $resDB);
   if($_POST['item_name'] == 'key1'){
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO downloads (downloadkey, file, expires) VALUES('{$strKey}', 'value1', '".(time()+(60*60*24*7))."')");
}elseif($_POST['item_name'] == 'key2'){
mysql_query("INSERT INTO downloads (downloadkey, file, expires) VALUES('{$strKey}', 'value2', '".(time()+(60*60*24*7))."')");{
}else($_POST['item_name'] == 'key3'){
mysql_query("INSERT INTO downloads (downloadkey, file, expires) VALUES ('{$strKey}', 'value3', '".(time()+(60*60*24*7))."')");
}
ecc...
```

is working.

Any idea why?

Please note that work is still in progress, so i know that i have to update mysql to mysqli.

Thanks for any suggestion

Comment: remove the IPN specific outside and just hit it with the browser once you have error reporting on. its nothing specific to do with it being an ipn script

Comment: Could you please be clearlier. Haven't understand anything. What do you mean with "Hit it with the browser" ?

Comment: Ok, think i understood now..still trying..**Edit**: Now it's working, thanks a lot for the answer!

Comment: no worries, IPN is not magic, its just like the page being visited by a normal person, jut with some extra information posted.

Comment: Follow the steps in this article about [how to test PayPal IPN](https://www.angelleye.com/test-paypal-ipn/) and you'll be able to find your problem.